# VBA 2015 "shape" Type undefined

Tags: vba, excel

I'm still somewhat new to VBA and I am having trouble defining an object as a shape. I have an excel worksheet with a rectangle and I would like to change the color of this shape from a comboBox in my VBA User Form. I have tried the code bellow and several other methods however I keep running into the error that "shape" is not a type, and this prevents me from using members such as fill. It might help to know I am using VBA 2015 as I know there are some differences between years

```
Dim rectangle as Shape
rectangle = sheet1.shapes("rectangle 1")
rectangle.Fill.Forecolor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
```

Comment: You need to use the `Set` keyword when assigning objects to variables: `Set rectangle = sheet1.shapes("rectangle 1")`

Comment: In 2015 you don't need the word "set" in order to assign objects. "Let" and "set" are no longer supported. Works just fine removing the word "set" all together.  However that still uses the "shape" type, which is what I am having the issue with

Comment: You absolutely do still need the `Set` keyword when assigning an object to an object variable.  Here is official documentation from the MSDN website for Office 2013 and later: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251642.aspx I couldn't find anything to support your claim that Let and Set are no longer supported.  Maybe that's true in Visual Basic, or .NET, or when creating custom classes?

Comment: Also note that you only need the `Set` keyword for object variables, it is not necessary (and will in fact cause an error) for non-object variables (such as strings, longs, etc)

Comment: All that being said, the `With` statement shown by @GordonBell should work just fine as an alternate solution.

Comment: Are you programming this in VB.NET or VBA? They are 2 completely different languages, and AFAIK there isn't a "VBA 2015".  You might end some of the confusion here by tagging the question with *the language you are programming in.*

Comment: Huh, whenever I use set I get an error with the description " 'Let' and 'Set' assignment statements are no longer supported" and the code leads me to think link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tzcse0s(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: That link it to VB.NET documentation, not VBA documentation.  If you opened Visual Basic from Excel, you're programming in VBA.  If you opened Visual Studio and referenced the Office Interop, you're programming in VB.NET.

Comment: Set is still required in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
With sheet1.shapes("rectangle 1")
    .Fill.Forecolor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End With
```

Comment: Thank you!  I tried that and I am no longer getting the same error but I'm getting the item not found error. The argument you pass through shapes is the cell name, right?

Comment: No, not the cell name, the shape name.  When you click on the Shape, it's name should appear in the little dropdown box on the Format tab.

Answer (score 0):

Run this to list shapes on Sheet1.  Are you sure you have a "Rectangle 1"?

```
Sub ListShapes()
    For Each s In Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes
        MsgBox s.Name
    Next
End Sub
```